# Declare and Loop using Stored Procedures/Macros in DB2 SQL

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, macros, db2, declare

I have a table_A which has names and delivery dates as follows

| Name | Del_dt |
| --- | --- |
| Mark | 2022-04-01 |
| Mark | 2022-04-03 |
| Mark | 2022-04-05 |
| Mark | 2022-04-07 |
| Mark | 2022-04-09 |
| Dave | 2022-04-02 |
| Dave | 2022-04-04 |
| Dave | 2022-04-06 |
| Dave | 2022-04-08 |
| Dave | 2022-04-10 |

and so on. I want to have a cumulative count of Name upto a particular date. For e.g. Output sample for date from 2022-04-07 to 2022-04-10

| Date | Name | cul_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 | Mark | 4 |
| 2022-04-08 | Mark | 4 |
| 2022-04-09 | Mark | 5 |
| 2022-04-10 | Mark | 5 |
| 2022-04-07 | Dave | 3 |
| 2022-04-08 | Dave | 4 |
| 2022-04-09 | Dave | 4 |
| 2022-04-10 | Dave | 5 |

Ofc the dates can be common for different names. I am trying to use Dynamic SQL (as I am a beginner and want to explore more). I have generated the following code based on what I could find about Dynamic SQL methods. I am also open to other methods too.

```
begin
    declare cur_date date;
    declare og_date date;
    declare Cust_Name varchar2(4);
    declare cul_cnt number;
    set cur_date = current_date; /*today's date*/
    set og_date = cur_date - 10; /*calculating cumulative counts for last 10 days*/
loop
    select Name,count(Name) into Cust_Name,cul_cnt,og_date
    from table_A
    where prod_type like 'SHOES' /*Another column in the table just for filter*/
    and Del_dt <= og_date
    group by Name;
    og_date = og_date + 1;
exit when (og_date > cur_date);
end;
end;
```

Currently I am getting this error

```
Error report -
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=CUR_DATE;SECTION, DRIVER=3.69.49
```

However, I am sure there would be more errors in the code. How can I get the desired output as shown in the Output table. Also, how do I get the og_date (Date column in output) as it is not present in the original table_A, but a defined variable

Comment: DB2 <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: @DaleK The `[sql]` tag is for Structured Query Language, not for MS SQL Server. MS SQL Server has its own `[sql-server]` tag here.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein I am well aware of that, I was referrjng to the "SQL Server" tag that was originally on this question - you can check the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 WITH 
-- Table of 10 dates generation starting from 2022-04-10
-- CURRENT_DATE can be used instead   
  D (I, DT) AS 
(
  SELECT 1, DATE ('2022-04-10') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
    UNION ALL
  SELECT I + 1, DT - 1 DAY FROM D WHERE I < 10
)
/*
, table_A (Name, Del_dt) AS 
(
          SELECT 'Mark', DATE ('2022-04-01') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', DATE ('2022-04-03') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', DATE ('2022-04-05') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', DATE ('2022-04-07') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', DATE ('2022-04-09') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', DATE ('2022-04-02') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', DATE ('2022-04-04') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', DATE ('2022-04-06') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', DATE ('2022-04-08') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', DATE ('2022-04-10') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
)
*/
SELECT D.DT, A.Name, A.cul_cnt
FROM D
CROSS JOIN TABLE 
(
  SELECT A.Name, COUNT (1) cul_cnt
  FROM table_A A
  WHERE A.Del_dt <= D.DT
  GROUP BY A.Name
) A
WHERE DT BETWEEN DATE ('2022-04-07') AND DATE ('2022-04-10')
ORDER BY A.Name DESC, D.DT
```

If you uncomment the commented out block, you may run the statement as is. The result in this case is the same as yours:

| DT | NAME | CUL_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-07 | Mark | 4 |
| 2022-04-08 | Mark | 4 |
| 2022-04-09 | Mark | 5 |
| 2022-04-10 | Mark | 5 |
| 2022-04-07 | Dave | 3 |
| 2022-04-08 | Dave | 4 |
| 2022-04-09 | Dave | 4 |
| 2022-04-10 | Dave | 5 |

The same query in Oracle:

```
WITH
  D (I, DT) AS 
(
  SELECT 1, TO_DATE ('2022-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
    UNION ALL
 SELECT I + 1, DT - INTERVAL '1' DAY FROM D WHERE I < 10
)
/*
, table_A (Name, Del_dt) AS 
(
          SELECT 'Mark', TO_DATE ('2022-04-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TO_DATE ('2022-04-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TO_DATE ('2022-04-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TO_DATE ('2022-04-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Mark', TO_DATE ('2022-04-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', TO_DATE ('2022-04-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', TO_DATE ('2022-04-04', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', TO_DATE ('2022-04-06', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', TO_DATE ('2022-04-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'Dave', TO_DATE ('2022-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL
)
*/
SELECT TO_CHAR (D.DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DT, A.Name, A.cul_cnt
FROM D
CROSS JOIN LATERAL 
(
  SELECT A.Name, COUNT (1) cul_cnt
  FROM table_A A
  WHERE A.Del_dt <= D.DT
  GROUP BY A.Name
) A
WHERE D.DT BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2022-04-07', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AND TO_DATE ('2022-04-10', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
ORDER BY A.Name DESC, D.DT
```

Comment: I tried running the 

WITH D (I, DT) AS 
(VALUES (1, '2022-04-10'::DATE)
 UNION ALL
 SELECT I + 1, DT - 1 DAY FROM D WHERE I < 10
)
Select * from D but I am getting the following errors
In Oracle: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword.       

In DB2: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-199, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=UNION;, ), DRIVER=3.69.49
I tried searching a lot on both of these but I couldn't find any solution

Comment: The [query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=9964270520627f7402d3fd636d8469e8) I provided works as described in Db2 for LUW. Don't try to run it in Oracle, since it must be a little bit modified to run there. What's your Db2 platform and version?

Comment: Anyway, I've rewritten the query to be valid for all Db2 platforms. Check it.

Comment: I don't know the DB2 Version but when I run this

SELECT GETVARIABLE('SYSIBM.VERSION') FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
I get DSN12015

The new version works perfectly fine. However can you tell me how to run this in Oracle? I can make the changes for all if you can just point me in the right direction. The Oracle version of Table_A has more data and therefore I need to query that. I used (select 1,sysdate from dual) for Oracle but got date as '27-APR-22' and I want the  date in the format of '2022-04-27'

Comment: See the updated answer